# Arabic Special Characters unicode \u064b \u064d \u0647 rendered incorrectly save as pdf

Tags: c#, aspose, aspose.words

Arabic Special Characters with Unicode
\u064b
\u064d
\u0647

Are rendered incorrectly when trying to save as PDF.
Attached is a sample VS2017 project, with a sample word file, and the code used for conversion, only omitting the license part.

Also check the support ticket on the Aspose free forums:

https://forum.aspose.com/t/arabic-special-characters-unicode-u064b-u064d-u0647-rendered-incorrectly-save-as-pdf/193389?u=mohamed.atia88

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: We have logged this problem as WORDSNET-18325 and will inform you once it is resolved. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.